# password stength not working as per rule

Tags: jquery, regex

how to update below code for this rules, I tried but always seems 
strong when I enter T&5 (UppercaseSymbolNumber).

> Rule:
>   at least 9 characters(Any)
>   two special characters
>   two numbers
>   two uppercase letters
>
> There will be two strength type:
>   1) Week: If not fulfill all Rules.
>   Then System will not allow for process
>   2) Good strong password  If
>   All rules fulfill - accept registration

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 10pt;
            }
            #password_strength
            {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="txtPassword" />
        <span id="password_strength"></span>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () { 
                $("#txtPassword").bind("keyup", function () {
                    //TextBox left blank.
                    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                        $("#password_strength").html("");
                        return;
                    }

                    //Regular Expressions.
                    var regex = new Array();
                    regex.push("[A-Z]"); //Uppercase Alphabet.
                    regex.push("[^A-Z$@$!%*#?&0-9]"); //Lowercase Alphabet.
                    regex.push("[0-9]"); //Digit.
                    regex.push("[$@$!%*#?&]"); //Special Character.

                    var passed = 0;

                    //Validate for each Regular Expression.
                    for (var i = 0; i < regex.length; i++) {
                        if (new RegExp(regex[i]).test($(this).val())) {
                            passed++;
                        }
                    }

                    //Validate for length of Password.
                    if (passed > 2 && $(this).val().length >= 9) {
                        passed++;
                    }

                    //Display status.
                    var color = "";
                    var strength = "";
                    switch (passed) {
                        case 0:
                        case 1:
                            strength = "Weak";
                            color = "red";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            strength = "Good";
                            color = "darkorange";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                        case 4:
                            strength = "Strong";
                            color = "green";
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            strength = "Very Strong";
                            color = "darkgreen";
                            break;
                    }
                    $("#password_strength").html(strength);
                    $("#password_strength").css("color", color);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: two downvotes for what? such a good question.

Comment: `passed > 2` means you only require 2 checks to be passed, however, you state *Good strong password If All rules fulfill*. Did you intend to write `passed === 4 `?

Comment: `T&5` matches 3 regexps - *Uppercase Alphabet*, *Digit* and *Special Character*  - and is thus strong. Did you fail to implement the check for 2 uppercase letters, digit and special char? Try `regex.push("[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z]");
regex.push("[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9]");
regex.push("[@$!%*#?&][^@$!%*#?&]*[@$!%*#?&]");`

Comment: Still does not work? Please share *your* fiddle.

Comment: When I add this text (AB%sqdf23) into textbox, it always shows strong, even there is only one special character. As per rule, at least 9 characters(Any)
two special characters
two numbers
two uppercase letters

Answer (score 1):

`T&5` matches 3 regexps - *Uppercase Alphabet*, *Digit* and *Special Character*  - and is thus *Strong*. If you need to check for *two* uppercase letters, *two* digits and *two* special characters, modify the existing regexps as follows:

```
regex.push("[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z]");
regex.push("[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9]");
regex.push("[@$!%*#?&][^@$!%*#?&]*[@$!%*#?&]");
```

These basically test for the character you want to require, then any 0+ characters other than those you require (defined with the negated character class equivalent (antonym class) with `*` quantifier), and then the second occurrence of the required character is matched with another instance of the initial character class.

Another point: **You only check the length when you have `passed` > `2`**. And if it is, you just increment `passed`. You need to add an additional check for the string length, and increment `passed` if it the requirement is met.

Have a look at the sample demo below.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#txtPassword").bind("keyup", function() {
    //TextBox left blank.
    var text = $(this).val();
    if (text.length == 0) {
      $("#password_strength").html("");
      return;
    }

    //Regular Expressions.
    var regex = new Array();
    regex.push("[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z]"); //Uppercase Alphabet.
    regex.push("[^A-Z$@$!%*#?&0-9]"); //Lowercase Alphabet.
    regex.push("[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9]"); //Digit.
    regex.push("[@$!%*#?&][^@$!%*#?&]*[@$!%*#?&]"); //Special Character.
    var passed = 0;

    //Validate for each Regular Expression.
    for (var i = 0; i < regex.length; i++) {
      if (new RegExp(regex[i]).test(text)) {
        console.log(text + " passed: " + regex[i]); // Console!
        passed++;                                   // Increment on match
      }
    }
    
    //Validate for length of Password.
    if (text.length >= 9) {
         console.log(text + " passed length check"); // Console!
      passed++;                                   // Increment if length is OK
    }
    
    //Display status.
    var color = "";
    var strength = "";
    switch (passed) {
      case 0:
      case 1:
        strength = "Weak";
        color = "red";
        break;
      case 2:
        strength = "Good";
        color = "darkorange";
        break;
      case 3:
      case 4:
        strength = "Strong";
        color = "green";
        break;
      case 5:
        strength = "Very Strong";
        color = "darkgreen";
        break;
    }
    $("#password_strength").html(strength);
    $("#password_strength").css("color", color);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

#password_strength {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtPassword" />
<span id="password_strength"></span>
```

Comment: your code is working, but what about  this rule :- at least 9 characters(Any)

Comment: Ok, got it. You only check the length when you have `passed` > 2. And if it is, you just increment `passed`. You need to add an additional check for the string length, even at the very beginning I guess, if it is such an important check. What is the expected behavior?

Comment: still not working, message not showing as per rule, there are only two messages

Comment: `T&5` is shown as `Weak`. What is your input and what is wrong with it?

Comment: Do you want to just disallow any string (what is the expected behavior?) if the whole input is less than 9 chars?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Regex

```
/^(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*].*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9]).{9,}$/
```

Explanation

```
^                         Start anchor
(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])        Ensure string has two uppercase letters.
(?=.*[!@#$&*].*[!@#$&*])  Ensure string has two special case letter.
(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])        Ensure string has two digits.
.{9,}                     Ensure string is of atleast length 9.
$                         End anchor.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (passed) {
                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                        strength = "Weak";
                        color = "red";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        strength = "Good";
                        color = "darkorange";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        strength = "Strong";
                        color = "green";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        strength = "Very Strong";
                        color = "darkgreen";
                        break;                        
                }
```